# How to get a value of a span coming as JSON response

Tags: jquery

I have something like this coming as a JSON reponse:

```
<span id=\"my-id-527114\">Some data here</span>\n <span id="my-differentid">something else</span>
```

is there any way to get the text  "Some data here"

Right now I am getting the text:

Here's my function:

```
$( "#myelementid" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "some remote url",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map(data, function( item ) {
                        if(item.value != " ")
                        {
                            var lbl = $(item.label);

                        return {

                                label: $(lbl).text(),
                                value: item.id
                            }
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Do `console.log( data );` and add results to your question.

Comment: {

    "id": "muurlvalue",
    "label": "\n <span class=\"KbArticle\">\n <span id=\"article-autocomplete-subject-527114\" >Question</span>\n <span id=\"article-autocomplete-body-527114\" class=\"article-autocomplete-body\">body</span>\n </span>\n ",
    "value": "some value"

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You response is not JSON. It's HTML/String.

```
              success: function( data ) {
                        if(item.value != " ") {

                            ......
                            var html = $(item),
                                text = $('span#my-id-527114', html).text();

                        } else {

                            .....
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Can I get it just by: $('span#my-id-', html).text(); I don't know the number

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string:

```
var spans = '<span id=\"my-id-527114\">Some data here</span>\n
             <span id="my-differentid">something else</span>'
```

You can convert it into document elements with jQuery, and access the content in the usual manner:

```
var text = $(spans).find('#my-id-527114').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might help.

```
var html = "<span id=\"my-id-527114\">Some data here</span>\n <span id="my-differentid">something else</span>
";

html = html.replace (/\n/i, "");
html = html.replace (/<\/span.*?$/, "");
html = html.replace (/<span.*?>/i, "");

alert (html); // what you want is here
```